# get convexhull points from array in openframeworks opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, openframeworks, convex-hull

I'm using openframeworks and opencv together and I'm trying to find the points of the convexhull. when i console log this method I get an array of all of the points but I need to be able to access specific points in the array.

When I console log the getConvexHull Method, I get the x and y points in the array:

```
 cout << "convexhull points" << contourFinder.getConvexHull(i) << endl;
```

And this is what the console gives me:

```
getconvexhull[243, 434;
  241, 443;
  243, 419]
```

How can I access the individuals points so I can reference them? I was thinking I need to do something like hull[0] but thats just returning [0, 0].

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto contourIndex = 0; contourIndex < contourFinder.size(); ++contourIndex)
{

    const ofPolyline contour = contourFinder.getPolylines()[contourIndex];

    ConvexHull convexHull(contour, hullMinumumDefectDepth);

    for (auto point: convexHull.convexHull()){
        ofSetColor(0,0,255, 100);
        ofDrawRectangle(point.x, point.y, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

This is what I did to get each points of convexHull and draw a blue rectangle on each point.
Hope it helps!